# Iframes in index.html Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, openid, angular2-template, openid-connect

I am building an angular application. For session management i am using OpenID Connect Session Management and i am trying to inject iframes . I have to include a iframe in index.html as

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Application </title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="./session.html" id="rp_session_iframe" width="0"
    height="0"></iframe>
    <div id="app-loader" class="app-loader"></div>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

and the content of session.html (same location as index.html) looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iFrame RP Page</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function()
        {
            window.parent.alert('iframesomething');
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But i am not able to see any alerts in my screen . And if i oberserve my source i can see recursive injection of iframes which  looks like

[image]

What am i doing wrong ? Please help.

Comment: I got similar problem, do you solve it ?

Comment: Its been a while a solved this. But if i remember correctly, i was using angular and i created the iframes dynamically and appnded the iframe to body. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

when a value (in your case the script tag) is inserted into the DOM from a template, via property, attribute, style, class binding, or interpolation, Angular sanitises and escapes untrusted values, because it treats all values as untrusted by default as is stated in their [documentation in security section](https://angular.io/guide/security).

But you can manually set trusted values with DomSanitizer, you can read more about how to implement it [here](https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis).

Hope it helps, have a great day. :)

Comment: Yes , but where would i sanitize when i am not even in a component. The html i am trying to add iframe to is root index.html